# Cómo realizar un Mock de un método Task<Func<T1,T2>>

Tags: c#, test, unittest, mock

Estoy queriendo "mockear" un método de una InterfaceService el cual tiene la siguiente firma:

```
public async Task<(int total, IEnumerable<Clase> clases)> GetClases(string claseId, string estadoId, int p, int pS)
```

Estoy usando los packages: NUnit, Moq y FluentAssertions

En mi test unitario pude realizar lo siguiente:

```
_mockService.Setup(x => x.GetClases(It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<Int32>(), It.IsAny<Int32>()))
                .ReturnsAsync( PARTE PROBLEMÁTICA )
```

La parte del Setup está correcta pero a la hora de realizar el **ReturnAsync** no comprendo cómo devolverle el valor esperado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera, lo que esperaba de retorno era una Tupla anónima por lo que declaré las siguientes locales y las invoqué en el ReturnAsync.

**Variables**

```
IEnumerable<Clase> instructions = new List<Clase>();
int total = 2;
```

**Mock del método**

```
_mockService.Setup(x => x.GetClases(It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<Int32>(), It.IsAny<Int32>()))
                .ReturnsAsync((total, instructions));
```

Comment: En tu pregunta está que necesitas `IEnumerable<Clase>` y ahora le das `IEnumerable<Instruction>` ¿Hubo algún cambio en el transcurso del desarrollo?

Comment: Ahí corregí la respuesta, no hubo ningún cambio, sólo era el nombre de la clase, lo quería hacer genérico por esa razón tenía el nombre Clase.

Comment: Ah vale, ¡perfecto! :D